# Saving an error exceptions to file erroring out

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, error-handling

I'm having some issues with a simple bit of code not working correctly and I'm totally baffled as to why...

```
errors = open('ERROR(S).txt', 'w')

try: 
    execfile("AEAPER.py")
except Exception as e:
    errors.write(e)

errors.close()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Sator.py", line 45, in <module>
    periodically(2, -1, +1, callscripts)
  File "C:\Sator.py", line 27, in periodically
    s.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\sched.py", line 117, in run
    action(*argument)
  File "C:\Sator.py", line 36, in callscripts
    errors.write(e)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

What is so wrong with my code and why is it doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the `print` statement, the [`file.write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) function only takes strings. So, you just need to convert to string explicitly:

```
errors.write(str(e))
```

Of course in real-life code, you often want to do some formatting, so you often forget about this this. For example:

```
errors.write('Failed to exec {} with {}'.format(filename, e))
```

Here, we're passing the result of `format` to `write`, which is fine, and we're passing `e` as an argument to `format`, which is also fine… the fact that we've done an implicit conversion to string in the middle is easy to miss.

There are actually two different ways to represent a value as a string, [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) and [`repr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr), but `str` is the one that `print` uses, so it's probably what you wanted here.

Answer (score 1):

`e` isn't a string. `write` needs a string. Make a string out of it with

```
repr(e)
```

or

```
str(e)
```

depending on what kind of output you want.

Answer (score 1):

The write() method expects a string as an argument. You need to convert the exception object to a string:

```
try: 
    execfile("AEAPER.py")
except Exception as e:
    errors.write(str(e))
```

See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write